# Keyhole Integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{k-1}}{(x+1)^2}dx}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you please integrate $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{k-1}}{(x+1)^2}dx}$$
using the keyhole integration.I tried to integrate like in $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\log{z}}{(z+1)^2}dx}$$ but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The large and small circles' integrals tend to zero provided that $0<k<2$. The pole is at $z=-1$, and being a double pole, we find its residue is
$$ \left. \frac{1}{1!}\frac{d}{dz} z^{k-1} \right\rvert_{z=e^{i\pi}} = (k-1)e^{(k-2)i\pi}. $$

For the contour above the real axis, we have
$$ I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx; $$
below, we have
$$ \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{(xe^{2i\pi})^{k-1}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx = -e^{2(k-1)i\pi} I $$
It follows by the residue theorem that
$$ 2\pi i (k-1) e^{(k-2)\pi i} = (1-e^{2(k-1)\pi i})I, $$
which you can rearrange to express the answer in terms of sines as
$$ I = \frac{(1-k)\pi}{\sin{k\pi}} $$