# More methods to evalute this integral ; $I=\int_0^2 x(8-x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I=\int_0^2 x(8-x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} \, dx$$
Being inept with integrals, this is my try,

$$\int x(8-x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} \, dx = (-1)\int x(x^3-8)^{\frac{1}{3}} \, dx $$

Using the substitution method (Chebyshev); for $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p \,dx$, where $m, n, p ∈ Q$, If $\frac{m+1}{n}+p ∈ Z$, then substitute $(ax^{-n}+b)=t^K$, where $K$ is the denominator of $p$;

$$\frac{(x^3-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x}=t ,\, dx=\frac{dt}{\left(\frac{x}{(x^3-8)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{(x^3-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x^2}\right)}$$

$$\int \frac{8t^3}{(t-1)^2(t^2+t+1)^2} \, dt=8 \left( \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{t^3-1}\,dt-\frac{1}{3}  \int \frac{t}{t^3-1} \, dt\right)$$

Continuing the partial fractions, the final result is;
$$\frac{8}{3} \left( \frac{\ln(t-1)}{3}-\frac{t}{t^3-1}-\frac{\arctan \left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt3}\right)}{\sqrt3} \right)-\frac{4}{9} \ln(t^2+t+1) $$

On putting the bounds, $I=\frac{16\pi}{(\sqrt3)^5}$

However, this is a very tedious method. In search for alternate method, i tried for beta functions, it resembled the format (almost). To bring it into the beta function form;

$B(p,q) = \int_0^1 x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1} \, dx$;

I tried with $x^3=8y$, which gave $I=\frac{8}{3} B\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3}\right)$ and using up almost all the properties;

1. $B(p,q)=\frac{\Gamma_p \Gamma_q}{\Gamma_{p+q}}$
2. $\Gamma_{p+1}=p(\Gamma_p)$
3. $\Gamma_p \Gamma_{1-p}=\frac{\pi}{sinp\pi}$, you get $I=\frac{16\pi}{(\sqrt3)^5}$.

I am interested in learning more ways to evaluate this integral.

Comment: $x=2\sin^{2/3}\theta$ substitution also leads to Beta function.

Comment: Hmm, I’d be hard pressed to come up with another method that isn’t just one of those two methods in disguise.

Comment: Maybe rewrite the integrand in terms of hypergeometric functions similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727505/convert-integral-int-0-frac-sqrt32-frac1x3-4-left-1-x/4727981#4727981)? (But I guess that's for crazy people like me.)

Comment: When does one get to call enough?

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{Res}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathfrak{D}}$Take $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ in the integral to obtain the equivalent expression: $$I=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^8x^{-1/3}(8-x)^{1/3}\d x$$Define a logarithm $\log':\Bbb C^\star\to\Bbb C$ through $-\pi\le\arg<\pi$ and  a logarithm $\log:\Bbb C^\star\to\Bbb C$ through $0\le\arg<2\pi$. For $z\in\Bbb C^\star$, denote by $z^{-1/3}$ the quantity $\exp\frac{-1}{3}\log(z)$ and for $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{8\}$ denote by $(8-z)^{1/3}$ the quantity $\exp\frac{1}{3}\log'(8-z)$.

Define $f:\Bbb C\setminus[0,8]\to\Bbb C$, $z\mapsto\frac{1}{3}z^{-1/3}(8-z)^{1/3}$. It follows from the choices of logarithm that the branch cuts on $[0,\infty),[8,\infty)$ cancel nicely to ensure $f$ is in fact holomorphic.

By considering the asymptotics of $f$ as $z\to\infty$ along the positive real axis (for simplicity's sake, and it's valid to restrict attention to that case since the power series exists), it's not too hard to see the $f$'s power series at $\infty$ must take the following form: $$f(z)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-\pi i/3}-\frac{8}{9}e^{-\pi i/3}z^{-1}+O(z^{-2})$$It follows that: $$\oint_{\D}f(z)\d z=2\pi i\res(f;\infty)=\frac{16\pi i}{9}e^{-\pi i/3}$$Where $\D$ is a clockwise dogbone contour that runs $0+i\delta\to8+i\delta\to8-i\delta\to-i\delta\to i\delta$ for some $\delta>0$. The section $-i\delta\to i\delta$ is a clockwise semicircular contour of radius $\delta$ that passes to the left of zero, and the section $8+i\delta\to8-i\delta$ is a clockwise semicircular contour of radius $\delta$ that passes to the right of $8$.

Letting $\delta\to0^+$ concludes: $$(1-e^{-2\pi i/3})I=\frac{16\pi i}{9}e^{-\pi i/3}$$Noting that $f(z)\to e^{-2\pi i/3}g(x)$ as $z\to x$ from below the real axis, if $g$ denotes the integrand of $I$, and noting also that the small semicircular integrals vanish since $\lim_{z\to0}zf(z)=0$ and $\lim_{z\to8}(z-8)f(z)=0$.

Thus: $$I=\frac{16\pi i}{9}\cdot\frac{\csc(\pi/3)}{2i}=\frac{16\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}$$As desired.

Comment: This was quite interesting, thanks.

Comment: FShrike, $\mathfrak D$ contains $0$ and $8$ but the function $f(z)$ is not defined at that two points, moreover I cannot understand why you consider $\text{Res}(f;\infty)$ if $\infty$ is external to $\mathfrak D$. And why $f(z)\to e^{-2\pi i/3}g(x)$ as $z\to x$ from below the real axis ? It seems that $f(z)\to g(x)$. I am sorry but I cannot understand a lot of things about your answer. And what do you mean when you write “*the branch cuts on $[0,\infty),[8,\infty)$ cancel nicely to ensure $f$ is in fact holomorphic*” ?
Please could you explain all it with more details ?

Comment: @Angelo Note for any $\delta>0$, $f$ is defined at every single point on the contour $\frak{D}$. So the integration is well-defined. The residue at infinity is always to be considered, and for a clockwise contour $\infty$ is *in*ternal to the contour on the Riemann sphere. That’s just a nice visualisation though, I know no advanced complex theory; it is nevertheless an extension of the residue theorem to include the residue at $\infty$, proven by taking a Laurent series expansion of $f$ at infinity.

Comment: Note that $\log z\to\ln x+2\pi i$ as $z\to x>0$ from below the real axis. Therefore $z^{-1/3}\to\exp(\ln x+2\pi i)/3=x^{-1/3}\cdot e^{-2\pi i/3}$, so overall $f(z)\to e^{-2\pi i/3}g(x)$

Comment: Finally for why $f$ is holomorphic outside of $[0,8]$: the only possible problem could be on $(8,\infty)$ where the exponentials individually have discontinuities. However if you take limits from above and below you find that the product $f$ doesn’t have any discontinuities; the ‘jumps’ by $e^{2\pi i/3}$ from each exponential will literally cancel. Think about why the logarithm is not holomorphic on the whole plane, if you don’t know what I mean in the last two comments

Comment: @Angelo "On $\mathfrak{D}$" is potentially ambiguous. The contour $\mathfrak{D}$ itself is just the line; to integrate $\oint_{\mathfrak{D}}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$, I need only that for every $t\in[0,1]$ that $f(\gamma(t))$ is defined, where $\gamma$ is some parametrisation of $\mathfrak{D}$ (... and that $f$ is integrable). Although $[0,8]$ is "enclosed" by $\mathfrak{D}$, $[0,8]$ does not intersect (the *trace* of) $\mathfrak{D}$. It is like integrating $\int_{[0,1]\cup[2,3]}h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, the values of $h$ on the "enclosed" interval $(1,2)$ are quite irrelevant

Comment: @FShrike, $0+i\delta\to8+i\delta\to8-i\delta\to-i\delta\to i\delta$ contains $0$ and $8$. Why do you say that $f$ is defined on $\mathfrak D$? $0\in -i\delta\to i\delta$ and $8\in 8+i\delta\to 8-i\delta$. Am I wrong ? Moreover, I believed that we have to consider only the poles inside the contour $\mathfrak D$ and for a clockwise contour we get the opposite result. Moreover, you said that $-\pi\leqslant\arg(\log z)<\pi$, but now you write that $\log z\to\ln x+2\pi i$ as $z\to x$ from below the real axis. Why ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I now see your confusion.

Comment: As is implied by "dogbone contour" (a known term) (but I will now edit and clarify this) the sections $-i\delta\to i\delta$ and $8+i\delta\to8-i\delta$ are semicircular indents that do not cross $[0,8]$

Comment: I made a typo with $\log z\to\ln x+2\pi i$, I meant $\log'z\to\ln x+2\pi i$. I've now swapped the meaning of $\log$ and $\log'$ in the post so as to correct this typo (I can't edit the comment). So, *now* it is correct that $\log z\to\ln x+2\pi i$.

Comment: Regarding "consider only the poles inside the contour" I can't really explain this without just writing a whole proof of this extension of the residue theorem. The usual residue theorem works by expanding in Laurent series about each pole inside the contour, here I am using a version where I expand in Laurent series about each pole outside the contour. Either is fine, both are correct theorems and yield the same answer *if* both apply. Here, the usual theorem doesn't apply because $f$ can't be extended to a meromorphic function on the interior of $\mathfrak{D}$.

Comment: You can think of it as just using the usual theorem on the modified function $g(z)=f(1/z)$ which is holomorphic on $B(0,1/8)$ with an essential singularity at $z=0$

Comment: @FShrike, thank you for you explanation. Congratulations for your answer (+1).

Comment: @Angelo thanks, and no worries. Dogbone integration is my favourite trick

Comment: @FShrike, how have you obtained the $f(z)$’s power series at $\infty$ ? I have obtained it in the following way:

Comment: @FShrike, $$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac13\exp\left(-\frac13\log z+\frac13\log’(8-z)\right)=\\[3pt]&=\frac13\exp\left(\frac13\log’\left(\tfrac8z-1\right)\right)=\\[3pt]&=\frac13\exp\left[\frac13\bigg(\!\!-i\pi+\log’\left(1-\tfrac8z\right)\bigg)\right]=\\[3pt]&=\frac13\exp\left[\frac13\left(-i\pi-\frac8z+o\!\left(\!z^{-1}\!\right)\right)\right]=\\[3pt]&=\frac13\exp\left(-\frac{i\pi}3\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\frac8{3z}+o\!\left(\!z^{-1}\!\right)\right)=\\[3pt]&=\frac13e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}3}\left(1-\frac8{3z}+o\!\left(\!z^{-1}\!\right)\right)\end{align}$$ Is it correct my way to get it ? Please correct it.

Comment: @FShrike, tell me how you have obtained it, please. What is your way to get the $f(z)$’s power series at $\infty$ ?

Comment: @Angelo That's all correct if you assume $z$ is a large real number. Then this result extends, because $f$ is holomorphic, to being valid for all large $z$. I should also note the residue at infinity is *minus* the $[z^{-1}]$ coefficient

Comment: @FShrike, thank you for your answer, but please could tell me how you obtained the power series of $f(z)$ at infinity ?

Comment: @Angelo Basically the same way you did! As I said, that’s correct

Answer (score 5):

Integrate the following general form by parts

\begin{align}
&\int_0^a x(a^3-x^3)^{1/3} \, dx\\
=& \int_0^a \frac{(a^3-x^3)^{1/3}}x\, d(\frac{x^3}3)
= \frac{a^3}3\int_0^a\frac x{(a^3-x^3)^{2/3}}\overset{a^3-x^3\to x^3}{dx}\\
=&\ \frac{a^3}3\int_0^a\frac 1{\sqrt[3]{a^3-x^3}}{dx}
= \frac{a^3}3\cdot \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}=\frac{2\pi a^3}{9\sqrt3}
\end{align}
where
$ \int_0^a\frac {dx}{\sqrt[3]{a^3-x^3}}= \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}$.

Comment: What's an easy elementary way to obtain $\int_0^a(a^3-x^3)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$?

Comment: @FShrike - With $x=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}}$
$$\int_0^1\frac {dx}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}} =\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^3}
\overset{t\to \frac1t}  =\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2-t+1}= \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3} $$

Comment: slick. I would default to contour integration if faced with such an integral

Comment: @Quanto are you a collage student?

Comment: @Quanto then? Anything like professor....

Comment: @LuckyChouhan neither of the like

Comment: @LuckyChouhan, Quanto is an incredibly advanced AI. There's _clearly_ no other possible explanation for always finding the shortest and slickest solutions (jk).

Comment: @RobertLee I think, he is [Cleo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/97378/cleo) of 2023 XD.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\displaystyle x = \frac{2}{(1+t)^{1/3}}$. Then

$$
I:= \int_{0}^{2}x\left(8-x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}dx = \frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\left(t+1\right)^{2}}dt = \frac{8}{3}\cdot\frac{\left(1-\frac{4}{3}\right)\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi\right)} = \frac{16\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}.
$$

Where for evaluating that last integral, we use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1252064).

Alternatively, let $x = \displaystyle \frac{2}{\left(u^{3}+1\right)^{1/3}}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
I &:= \int_{0}^{2}x\left(8-x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}dx \\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{3}}{\left(1+u^{3}\right)^{2}}du \\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{3}+1-1}{\left(1+u^{3}\right)^{2}}du \\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{3}}du-8\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+u^{3}\right)^{2}}du \\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{3}}du-8\left(\left[\frac{u}{3\left(u^{3}+1\right)}\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{3}+1}du\right) \tag{1}\\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{3}}du-\frac{16}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{3}+1}du \\
&= \frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{3}}du \\
&= \frac{16\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}. \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

$(1)$ We use Ostrogradsky's method by letting $P(u) = 1$, $Q(u) = (1+u^3)^2$, $Q_1(u) = Q_2(u) = u^3+1$, and we find $P_1(u) = u/3$ and $P_2 (u) = 2/3$.

$(2)$ We use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556115/compute-int-0-infty-fracdx1x3).

Comment: Oh @Accelerator! I literally found its closed form like this. Cheers, What I think is while  trying to evaluate integrals feynman's technique, beta and gamma functions can be very helpful at any time.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan You might want to post that as an answer then. :)

Comment: You got it. But you already posted so I don't think I should.

Comment: Great answer, would love to share the result you linked at your last line, for $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}  dx = \frac{\pi}{n}cosec(\frac{\pi}{n})$, n being natural

Comment: @Ercanayan Honestly, I was too lazy to provide my own work for that last line. When I got to that last line, I figured it was shared a billion times on the Internet so I decided to link one result.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $x=2\sin^{\frac 23}\theta$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{16}{3} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{\frac{1}{3}} \theta \cos ^{\frac{5}{3}} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{16}{3} \cdot\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{4}{3}\right) \\
& =\frac{8 \pi}{3} \cdot \csc \frac{\pi}{3}  \quad  (\textrm{By } B(x,1-x)=\pi\csc (\pi x))\\
& =\frac{16 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation based upon binomial expansion and *[hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)*. We also use the rising factorial notation $(a)_{n}:=a(a+1)\cdots(a+n-1)$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{2}}\color{blue}{x\left(8-x^3\right)^{1/3}\,dx}
> &=2\int_{0}^{2}x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n}\left(-\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^n\,dx\\
> &=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^n\int_{0}^2x^{3n+1}\,dx\\
> &=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^n\left.\frac{1}{3n+2}x^{3n+2}\right|_0^2\\
> &=8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+2}}_{:=t_n}\\
> &=8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t_n=8t_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{t_{j+1}}{t_j}\\
> &=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{j+1}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{3j+5}
> \binom{\frac{1}{3}}{j}^{-1}(-1)^{-j}(3j+2)\\
> &=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(j-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(j+\frac{2}{3}\right)}
> {(j+1)\left(j+\frac{5}{3}\right)}\\
> &=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)_n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)_n}{\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)_n}\,\frac{1}{n!}\\
> &=4{}_2F_{1}\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};1\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=4\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(1)}\tag{2}\\
> &=4\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}\Gamma(3)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{16\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the sum as hypergeometric $_2F_1$ function evaluated at $z=1$ .
- In (2) we recall a theorem from C. F. Gauss [1812] (see e.g. Theorem 2.2.2 in *[Special Functions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/special-functions/1F1C575CEA780EE774F5518C7963BF08#fndtn-information)* by G.E. Andrews, R. Askey and R. Roy) which is
  \begin{align*}
  {_2F_1}(a,b;c;1)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}\tag{4}
  \end{align*}
  if $\Re(c-a-b)>0$. We derive from (1) $\Re\left(\frac{5}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{4}{3}>0$ and we can apply (4).
- In (3) we use $\Gamma(2)=\Gamma(1)=1$ and the Gamma triplication formula
  \begin{align*}
  \Gamma (3z)=(2 \pi)^{-1}3^{3z-1/2}\Gamma(z)\Gamma \left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)
  \end{align*}
  evaluated at $z=1$.

Comment: just started learning integral representation of hypergeometric functions, really neat answer!

Comment: @Ercanayan: Just the right time for my answer. Here you go. :-)